# How to avoid application crashing when launching AlertDialog using AsyncTask() in ANDROID?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

In an Android application, by clicking a button, in a fragment, I want to show an AlertDialog using AsynTask() method. I have put, in `onPreExecute()`, the function which called the `AlertDialog`. In `doInBackground()`, there is a task running, and in `onPostExecute()`, I dismiss the `AlertDialog`.
The crash occurs just when I click the button. And it refers to line code in the LoadingDialog class, which is `dialog.show();`. I have tried many suggestions given on the site, but, the issue occurs again.
Could anyone help me?

This is the `LoadingDialog.java`

```
    public class LoadingDialog {

    private Activity activity;
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    LoadingDialog(Activity myActivity){
        activity = myActivity;
    }

    public void startLoadingDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null));
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void dismissDialog(){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    }
```

This is my Fragment class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    View view ;
    private Button btn_;
    private Activity activity;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private LoadingDialog loadingDialog;

    public MyFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);

        loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(getActivity());

        btn_ = this.view.findViewById(R.id._button);
        eventListnerReinitialiser();
        return this.view;
    }

    public void eventListnerReinitialiser() {
        this.btn_.setOnClickListener(v -> {
             new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();
        });
    }

    public class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        int s = 0;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            loadingDialog.startLoadingDialog();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
                s = s + i;
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Valeur de s = "+ s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            loadingDialog.dismissDialog();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

}
```

And I have this error log in my console of Android studio

```
    E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.myproject.Menu2Activity has leaked window DecorView@96c506[] that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:511)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:338)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing a toast in the `doInBackground()` of the AsyncTask, and this cannot be done. **You can only update the Ui in the main thread.**

Showing the toast in the `doInBackground()` which is **running in a  background thread** throws a exception and your fragment is forced to shutdown at that moment but the dialog is still open which caused the exception.

So try calling the `Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Valeur de s = "+ s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;` in the `onPostExecute` of AsyncTask.

Here is how to do the AsyncTask part.

```
public class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        int s = 0;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            loadingDialog.startLoadingDialog();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for(int i=0;i<100_000_000;i++)
                s = s + i;

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Valeur de s = "+ s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
            loadingDialog.dismissDialog();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response @Vivek Singh, I have tried what you have said. But the dialog dismisses quickly even if the task in doInBackground is not still finished,

Comment: I have changed the task in the doInBackground(), and I have added a Toast in the onPostExecute()to know that the task is finished or not. By waiting for some minutes, the toast happens, but during these minutes, the dialog doesn't show,

Comment: @zayann how do you know that the task in the doInBackground() is still not finished, considering that counting to 1000000 is a quick task

Comment: @zayann so you are saying that you are not seeing the dialog at all

Comment: By doing the test again  and again, I see the dialog, at most, around in one second, then it disappears.  The Toast in the onPosExecute( ) is happenning after that,

Comment: @zayann I tested your code and it is just working fine as expected, you press the button ,the dialog shows for some time, then it dismisses and then the toast appears. I updated my answer with my code for the async task.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Vivek said also:

1. Change the ShowDialogAsyncTask to static class
2. pass the dialog as WeakReference then use weakReference.get() in each place where it is
   used
3. To show dialog pass context.getApplicationContext() as weak reference.

Currently your Activity is leaking through AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you @Karol Szczepański for your advice, but please, could you give an example about what you have said in step 2 and 3, I don't understand very well,